# Are obvious cybereyes cheaper?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

A player recently got the idea that obvious cybereyes should be cheaper, just like obvious cyberlimbs.

I disagreed, but for the sake of group morale I'm asking here. If possible, I would like a rule-as-written, but I accept also good reasoning.

---

His vision how his eyes will look like:
[image: Who ever read these?]
<sub>Picture converted to jpg from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ghost_in_the_Shell_Stand_Alone_Complex_Batou.png#/media/File:Ghost_in_the_Shell_Stand_Alone_Complex_Batou.png)</sub>

In my opinion the technology in Shadowrun 5 is far enough to produce a life-like eye if requested. Upon close examination the eye will of course be detectable as a artificial object, but in general daily contact the difference should not be visible.

Of course any character can decide to drastically alter the appearance of the eyes (to a certain degree), for example full-black, rainbow or a slightly altered form. This is the characters decision however and not a "fault" in the cybereye (IMO).

Comment: My first guess based on watching a bunch of sci-fi movies would be sunglasses make it really easy to hide cyber-eyes, so even obvious ones aren't obvious most of the time.

Comment: Also, maybe the upcoming book on Cyberware will say something about this. You'll have to wait for it, though, as far as I know it is currently in print (as of 29.06.2015)

Comment: Are they just trying to get a good deal on a set of eyes? What's the harm in giving it to them? It's kind of clever.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald They try to squeeze everything, and it is getting ridiculous.

Comment: I see! Yeah, that can get annoying for sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rules-as-written does not address the obviousness of cybereyes.  It does reference that you can get unnatural patterns or colors in your eye, but you can get those as retinal modifications to natural eyes as well, so even a rainbow colored cat's eye isn't obviously cybernetic.

Note that if you're running a "realistic" or gritty game, the eyes in your image reference wouldn't be able to take in light anyway, so calling them eyes is a bit of a stretch.  They could be ultrasound, magnetic, or something like that, though.  But long story short, **you're right, both in the rules and in the "fluff", cybereyes are non-obvious by default and obvious cybereyes give no discount.**  The serious engineering challenges to hide cyberlimbs and the expense of creating coverings and things simply don't apply.

Answer (score 5):

You want something RAW, then there's no real rules for cyber-eyes that are 'obvious'.  The only things that have rules, at this time, are cyberlimbs.  This has a lot to do with how easy it would be to cover up 'obvious' cyber eyes.

That doesn't mean that, as the DM, you can't institute a rule like that.  Use the same rules as cyber limbs and you should be fine.  But, your question is the RAW, and RAW doesn't give you obvious cyberware outside of limbs.